# How to add a project in a private repository in GitHub which is contains programs from others projects?

Tags: git, github, repository

The case is: I have cloned/downloaded some of the projects, I have used this as part of my project and also I modified slightly according to my project requirement.

Now I want upload my project as a private repository.

How to do it because it contains some of the borrowed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the all set of files is only one Git repo (in which you copied/modified other repos content), you can simply add a remote to a new private Git repo.

First create an *empty* new private project on gitlab.

Then in your local repo:

```
git remote add origin /url/private/gitlab/repo
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Some of the libraries are just borrowed and they are open source, will there be not a issue of plagiarism?

Comment: @MArjun It depends on their license: https://github.com/blog/1530-choosing-an-open-source-license. For instance, if MIT, you can go ahead and copy without any issue.